# Execute script at intervals in php

Tags: php, execute

i would like to execute a script every 2 minutes until i close the window.My script am executing every 2 minutes writes to a file. My script is not writing to the file. please see my interval script.

```
<?php
$interval = 1; //minutes
set_time_limit (0);
while (true)
{
  $now=time ();
  echo $now . "<BR>";
  sleep ($interval * 1 - (time () - $now));
}
?>
```

Comment: Uhm... `sleep(120)`...?

Comment: @deceze : you are right. Here change the sleep functions parameter with 120 and remove other unwanted code.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
<?php
function do_stuff(){

  // do something

 sleep(20); // wait 20 seconds
 do_stuff(); // call this function again
}
?>
```

Comment: the problem is this function never returns, and it will constantly take up memory

Comment: @MihaiRaulea right, that is what recursive function do,  but you need to break or exit out of the function as per your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

`sleep` takes as param number of seconds so you should write `sleep($interval * 60)`

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to add `flush()` after each `echo`.  Also `sleep` want time in seconds, not in minutes, so your `$interval` should probably be set to `60` rather than to `1`.

Answer (score 1):

sleep() is definitely not the solution (I wonder why is is even considered here ...)
After a lot of experimenting I have arrived to the following solution: Execute "timed" PHPs (i.e. executed at intervals) via an HTML file containing a javascript timer and a frame:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var obj;
var interval = {interval_msecs}; 
var PHP_to_execute = "http://localhost/Work/{yourPHP}.php";  
var timer = setInterval(function(){exec()}, interval);
function exec() {
  obj = document.getElementById("PHParea");
  obj.src = PHP_to_execute;
} 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="PHParea" src=""></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the basis (using a localhost). You can add whaterever feature you want to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);

$interval=1; //minutes
echo str_repeat(" ", 1024);
while(true) {
    $now=time();
    echo $now."<BR>";
    sleep($interval * 60);
    flush();
}
?>
```

Comment: Is there a way I can first echo a Welcome, then the interval script kicks in?